# Elasticsearch: can you use the results of aggregates in the same search?

Tags: elasticsearch, nosql

we have an Elasticsearch index with about 50000 "product" entries per user over which our app performs complex queries. Each of those entries has a corresponding "supplier" and "supervisor". The suppliers and supervisors are stored in their own indices, and there are only ~200 of each per user. They are big documents, so in the product index we store just their name and ID, which are the only things used in queries over products. However, on each product query we would also like to return aggregate information about suppliers and supervisors. Example: if the query returns 800 products and they have 10 different suppliers and 12 different supervisors, I want information on those. I know how to use bucket aggregates over their IDs, (or names treated as keyword). However these results return only their ID or name. Is there any way to retrieve all the information from the supplier and supervisor documents using these aggregate IDs on the same query? Or do I have to perform a second query?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please update your question with the **desired behavior, specific problems, and code to reproduce i**t. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @wehodo8527 Yes you are correct, you would need to perform a second query. ES is not meant to perform join operations. Either you need to denormalise the data(make sure you read about `nested` type if you wish to add more details about `supervisor` and `supplier` data) or you need to manage that type of `join logic` at your application layer.